# Time series and fitted values side by side in one time series / data frame / graph

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, lm

I am using `dlnm` and `lm` to fit a linear model of a number of time series. I would like to visually compare the fitted values with the actual values, and so I want to export both in one csv file. However, it appears that I cannot use `ts.intersect` to bind them because `$fitted.values` of the model is not a time series. The documentation of `lm` [suggests](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) that `$fitted.values` will be a time series if `na.action = NULL` is passed to the `lm`. However, this is only possible if the values used as input are defined everywhere, which is not the case if `crossbasis` is applied with non-trivial lag.

Is there a convenient way to get the actual and fitted time series side by side?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not plotting the values directly in R, since you did the estimation there?

Comment: I find spreadsheet graphs easier to work with, but will happily be convinced otherwise, in particular if plotting the values directly in R in one graph is easier to achieve.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to plot in `R`. I would say it's one of the main areas of that keeps getting developed almost monthly. `ggplot2` is the major package for plotting outside of base - http://ggplot2.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've found a reasonable workaround to reconstruct fitted.values as a time series. `ts.intersect` does not work with `zoo` series, `merge` is the appropriate function:

```
actual <- actual.values
fit <- read.zoo(data.frame(names(model$fitted.values),model$fitted.values))
result <- merge(actual,fit,all=FALSE) #default all=TRUE gives union
```